# How do I subscribe to a Event in .net Core?

Tags: dependency-injection, .net-core, event-handling

I’m using .net Core dependcy injection in an MVC project.

A controller route is requested and uses an injected service (ServiceA) that - upon the services method being completed, raises an event (of Action) in a method of the service.  This service is registered as a transient in the container.

I have another service that is also registered in the container as a transient (ServiceB) that should subscribe to the action of ServiceA whenever it’s instantiated/resolved by the container so that it’s “wired up” to the Action that’s raised by it.  ServiceB can know about ServiceA but ServiceA should not know about ServiceB.

How is this achieved? Since ServiceA does not have and immediate dependency on ServiceB it is never instantiated by dependcy injection and therefore never subscribes to ServiceAs Event/Action

I am aware of other approaches such as implementing IObservable but would like to know the approach instead for this scenario.

Heres the example:

```cs
public class Startup
{
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddTransient<IServiceA, ServiceA>();
        services.AddTransient<IServiceB, ServiceB>();
    }
}

public interface IServiceA
{
    event Action<string> OnCompletedDoSomething;
    void DoSomething();
}

public class ServiceA : IServiceA
{
    public event Action<string> OnCompletedDoSomething;

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        OnCompletedDoSomething?.Invoke("Did it!");
    }
}

public interface IServiceB
{
    void EventListener(string message);
}

public class ServiceB : IServiceB
{
    private IServiceA _serviceA;

    public ServiceB(IServiceA serviceA)
    {
        _serviceA = serviceA;

        _serviceA.OnCompletedDoSomething += new Action<string>(EventListener);
    }

    public void EventListener(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private IServiceA _serviceA;

    public HomeController(IServiceA serviceA)
    {
        _serviceA = serviceA;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        _serviceA.DoSomething();
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include some code as a [mcve] to give a better understanding of what it is you are trying to achieve